# Unable to open and read file using fopen and fread function

Tags: php

The following script bring up a "programming error". I am logged in as the owner of the file so I am not sure why I get the error. I have tried both relative and absolute paths.

Any help very much appreciated.

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "r") or 
die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("test.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: I would say test.txt contains the text "programming error"

Comment: Do you get an error that literally says "programming error"?

Comment: @eskimo it is when displayed on the browser..website under maintenance ....or ... programming error

Comment: Ah ok cool. First make sure the file actually exists (open it in your browser eg: http://website.com/test.txt). Then make sure the [permissions are correct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php). Then, try `fopen(gwtcwd()."/test.txt", "r")`

Comment: @eskimo I played with it again and it works! thank you!

Comment: Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

what means "I am logged in as the owner"? Do you run the script via the command line, or from a webspace?
If you run the script from a webpage, most of the time, the "www-data" user runs the process. Change the permissions for your file "test.txt", that the user which executes the script, e.g: "www-data" has at least read permissions.
It would be interresting to see your current permissions of "test.txt". I would bet that you have an issue with your permissions.